# Knockoutjs template: How to use 1 object array for 2 DOM elements after filtering that array by some property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a template and a 'bindingHandler' named 'employees' and an Array of employees.

I want to use the same object array of employees (for the template) in 2 different elements but every element has different data of the array.

for example:
I have an array of employees (that I'm getting from the server) like this:

```
var employees = [
        { FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'John', JobTitleCode: 101 },
        { FirstName: 'Guest', LastName: 'Guest', JobTitleCode: 15 },
        { FirstName: 'David', LastName: 'David', JobTitleCode: 300 },
        { FirstName: 'Ryan', LastName: 'Ryan', JobTitleCode: 300 },
        { FirstName: 'Alex', LastName: 'Alex', JobTitleCode: 10 },
        { FirstName: 'Michael', LastName: 'Michael', JobTitleCode: 101 }
    ];
```

And my HTML is like this:

```html
<div>
  <b>Job title code 101</b>
  <div data-bind="employees: { employeesModel: Employees, jobTitleCode: 101 }" />
</div>

<br/>

<div>
  <b>Job title code 300</b>
  <div data-bind="employees: { employeesModel: Employees, jobTitleCode: 300 }" />
</div>
```

I need all those employees with JobTitleCode 101 on the first div element and those with JobTitleCode 300 on the second div element.

Here is my Template and the Binding handler:

```js
(function () {
 
 ko.employeeModel = function (config) {
  var self = this;
  self.Exclude = config.exclude || [];
  self.AllEmployees = config.employees;

  self.Employees = ko.pureComputed(function () {
   return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.AllEmployees, function (employee) {
    return $.inArray(employee.JobTitleCode, self.Exclude) == -1;
   });
  });
 };

 var templateEngine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();

 templateEngine.addTemplate = function (templateName, templateMarkup) {
  document.write("<script type='text/html' id='" + templateName + "'>" + templateMarkup + "</script>");
 };

 templateEngine.addTemplate("ko_employees", "\
                                <div data-bind=\"foreach: Employees\">\
                                    <div>\
                                        <label data-bind=\"text: FirstName\"></label>\
                                        <label data-bind=\"text: LastName\"></label>\
          <label data-bind=\"text: JobTitleCode\"></label>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>");

 ko.bindingHandlers.employees = {
  init: function () {
   return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
  },

  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
   var accessor = valueAccessor();
   var viewModel = accessor.employeesModel ? accessor.employeesModel : accessor;
   var jobTitleCode = accessor.jobTitleCode ? accessor.jobTitleCode : 0;

   while (element.firstChild) {
    ko.removeNode(element.firstChild);
   }

   var attachmentsTemplateName = "ko_employees"

   var employeesContainer = element.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
   ko.renderTemplate(attachmentsTemplateName, viewModel, { templateEngine: templateEngine }, employeesContainer, "replaceNode");
  }
 };
})();
```

And finally the viewmodel:

```
var vm = function (employeeArr) {
        var self = this;
        self.Employees = new ko.employeeModel({
            exclude: [10, 15],
            employees: employeeArr
        });
    }

    // data from server
    var employees = [
        { FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'John', JobTitleCode: 101 },
        { FirstName: 'Guest', LastName: 'Guest', JobTitleCode: 15 },
        { FirstName: 'David', LastName: 'David', JobTitleCode: 300 },
        { FirstName: 'Ryan', LastName: 'Ryan', JobTitleCode: 300 },
        { FirstName: 'Alex', LastName: 'Alex', JobTitleCode: 10 },
        { FirstName: 'Michael', LastName: 'Michael', JobTitleCode: 101 }
    ];

    var emloyeeVm = new vm(employees);
    ko.applyBindings(emloyeeVm);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Michael, can you point out what is not working?

Comment: Hi Michael, the result of the 2 divs must be different, for now the 2 divs are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom binding handlers are *not* the correct tool for your requirement IMHO. Custom binding handlers are meant for handling special DOM interaction, e.g. creating a popup component or a datepicker. You are reinventing the `foreach` binding instead, and doing view model logic inside of it.

Here's an alternative appproach. The key is to use `computed` observables to get seperate lists:

```js
var vm = function (employeeArr) {
  var self = this;
  var exclude = [10, 15];
  
  self.employees = ko.observableArray(employeeArr);
  
  self.groups = ko.computed(function() {
    var groups = [], result = [];
    self.employees().forEach(function(e) {
      if (exclude.indexOf(e.JobTitleCode) < 0) {
        if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(e.JobTitleCode)) {
          groups[e.JobTitleCode] = { key: e.JobTitleCode, people: [] };
          result.push(groups[e.JobTitleCode]);
        }
        groups[e.JobTitleCode].people.push(e);
      }
    });
    return result;
  });
}

// data from server
var employees = [
  { FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'John', JobTitleCode: 101 },
  { FirstName: 'Guest', LastName: 'Guest', JobTitleCode: 15 },
  { FirstName: 'David', LastName: 'David', JobTitleCode: 300 },
  { FirstName: 'Ryan', LastName: 'Ryan', JobTitleCode: 300 },
  { FirstName: 'Alex', LastName: 'Alex', JobTitleCode: 10 },
  { FirstName: 'Michael', LastName: 'Michael', JobTitleCode: 101 }
];

var emloyeeVm = new vm(employees);
ko.applyBindings(emloyeeVm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="group101">
  <b data-bind="text: key"></b>
  <div data-bind="foreach: people">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: LastName"></span>        
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="group300">
  <b data-bind="text: key"></b>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
      <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: LastName"></span>        
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>

<!-- ko foreach: groups -->
<hr>
<div data-bind="template: 'group' + key"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, but my need is (for example) to split the same array in different DOM elements using the same template. For now the result of 2 divs are identical and should'nt be.

Comment: @Michael Ah yes, makes sense. I'd suggest using dynamicly picked templates (or even components) for that. I've updated my answer accordingly.